# Where does postfix store messages awaiting relay?

Tags: postfix

If I specify a relayhost in main.cf, in what path (by default) does postfix store that message before and during the process of relaying it on to the next server? And is there a parameter that allows that path (or paths) to be customized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix will store mails waiting to be sent in the [`queue_directory`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#queue_directory).

See `postconf` for the current value.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing it is /var/spool/mail/$USER somewhere.

Comment: Not for a relay.